# What does 'give me a stomachache' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In [this video](https://youtu.be/P4GQMi8udGo?t=241), the youtuber says,

> This is going to **give me a stomachache**, yes. Will I drink the rest of it? Also yes. It is so milky. It's like a milky sugar with like just a little bit of coffee. It's not that great. But you know what, I'm gonna drink it. I'm going to give the Greg's latte ME TIME, I'm gonna give it one out of six ME TIME. It's doable. If you are in a rush and you need that iced latte, fine, okay.

What does 'give me a stomachache' mean here? My first impression is that it means the taste of the latte is horrible. But that interpretation contradicts the youtuber's intention to drink the rest of it. Also, she says it's doable. So, I'm confused.

Comment: If something gives you a stomachache, it gives you a pain (ache) in your stomach, not just an unpleasant taste in your mouth.

Comment: You're right in identifying a contradiction, but those are the senses of the words. It's a joke: "It'll give me a stomachache, but I'll drink it anyway, because I'm so curious and foolish!"

Answer (score 1):

It means "give you pain in your belly".

The youtuber says that they will drink it *even though* they expect to get a stomachache.  It is not clear why...  <sub>perhaps because althogh it doesn't have a sophisticated taste, your caveman brain just wants calories.  This feeds that unsophisticated taste.</sub>